# KGDB error code '22' using kgdboc

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, error-code, kgdb

I'm currently trying to debug a board using a PowerPC 500v2 processor.  When I try to connect to the board using gdb while the board is ready for me it gives me the status

```
qTStatus: Target returns error code '22'.
0x00004100 in ?? ()
qTStatus: Target returns error code '22'.
```

With remote debug 1 set:

```
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyS6
Sending packet: $qSupported:multiprocess+;xmlRegisters=i386;qRelocInsn+#b5...Ack
Packet received: 
Packet qSupported (supported-packets) is NOT supported
Sending packet: $Hg0#df...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $qTStatus#49...Ack
Packet received: E22
qTStatus: Target returns error code '22'.
Sending packet: $?#3f...Ack
Packet received: S05
Sending packet: $Hc-1#09...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $qC#b4...Ack
Packet received: QC00000000000002bc
Sending packet: $qAttached#8f...Ack
Packet received: 
Packet qAttached (query-attached) is NOT supported
Sending packet: $qOffsets#4b...Ack
Packet received: 
Sending packet: $g#67...Ack
Packet received: (Ton of Random Numbers)
Sending packet: $m40c0,1#c1...Ack
Packet received: E14
Sending packet: $m40c0,1#c1...Ack
Packet received: E14
Sending packet: $m40c0,8#c8...Ack
Packet received: E14
Sending packet: $m40c0,7#c7...Ack
Packet received: E14
Sending packet: $m40c0,40#f4...Ack
Packet received: E14
0x000040c0 in ?? ()
Sending packet: $qSymbol::#5b...Ack
Packet received: 
Packet qSymbol (symbol-lookup) is NOT supported
Sending packet: $qTStatus#49...Ack
Packet received: E22
qTStatus: Target returns error code '22'.
```

I'm running an older kernel (2.6.27) on a single serial port for display and debugging.  I mainly use the echo ttySX > /sys/module/kgdboc/parmeters/kgdboc and echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger for setting up, but I have also tried kernel arguments on boot and it does not seem to make a difference.  For some reason when I quit gdb it seems to send the exit data fine to the board (the board stops pausing) but none of the other commands seem to work.

Comment: Did you find anything related to this? I'm also getting the same error. Would love to hear from you

Comment: I was not able to make it work in the end and didn't look into it further.  If I remember correctly a recent patch made it not able to function on this older kernel and to make it work you would need to recompile an older version.  Sorry that I am not more help.

Comment: You mentioned `If I remember correctly a recent patch made it not able to function on this older kernel`, so by __patch__ do you mean a recent gdb patch??

Comment: I think it was kgdb actually.  They found some stability bug with regular serial output and completely changed it if I remember correctly.  A lot of the documentation ended up being wrong due to this change.